# Number of cliques in intersection graphs in hyperconvex metric spaces

Tags: graph-theory, metric-spaces, convex-geometry

I would like to find out if it is known whether intersection graphs of closed unit balls in h[yperconvex metric spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_metric_space) have polynomially many cliques.

A metric space is *hyperconvex*  if it is convex, and its closed balls have the "binary Helly property", i.e., if a collection of closed balls intersects pairwise, then they all do.

There is [some information](https://dmtcs.episciences.org/387) known about graphs "with few cliques" (i.e., polynomially many), and the relationship of this graph class to Helly intersection number, but I am wondering if the Helly property of balls in hyperconvex spaces implies that an intersection graph of closed balls in a hyperconvex space necessarily falls into this class.

So-called "[Helly graphs](https://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_105.html)" are the "discrete analog" of hyperconvex metric spaces, but I don't think it necessarily follows that an intersection graph in a hyperconvex space is necessarily a Helly graph. Or is it?

**Edit 1**: [Spinrad](https://bookstore.ams.org/fim-19) argues (without proof) that boxes (axis-parallel rectangles) in $\mathbb R^d$ having the Helly property implies that the number of maximal cliques of an $n$-vertex graph with [boxicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxicity) $k$ is $O(n^k)$, so the origin for my question is wondering if the Helly property of closed balls in hyperconvex spaces would yield a similar bound of polynomial size for the number of cliques of intersection graphs there.